# Delivery Date Changes Price field value with New Custom Field

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I got project with following requirements:

1. The customer should be able to select **delivery date**(date popup) in the **checkout form**.
2. The administrator can set **special delivery date**, in configuration settings.
3. If the customer select a **delivery date** that matches with **special delivery date**, the **prices** will **change**.
4. There are **2 price field** in **1 product reference**. The **default price field** and **custom special price field**.
5. **Price value** will **change** according to the **delivery date** that the customer selected.

For example:

Case 1:

1. The **admin** set Special date to be: Feb 14, 2016
2. The **customer** selected delivery date: March 2, 2016
3. The final product price uses the **default price field** value.

Case 2:

1. The **admin** set Special date to be: Feb 14, 2016
2. The **customer** selected delivery date: Feb 14, 2016 (**match**)
3. The final line item product price will use the value that was set in the **custom price field**.

What would be the workaround with this one. I feel stuck with my module. I was thinking if I need to use rules instead. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules will be the best option in the above mentioned cases. You can use "data validation" to compare both fields and set value of the "product price" field accordingly

Comment: What would be the Event that will trigger this?